# Moving Dialog with click and hold in title

Tags: qt, dialog, qtquick2

Is there possibility by default to drag `Dialog` windows (not native ones) by click and hold them in title?

I use `Dialog` from `import QtQuick.Controls 2.2`. Header contains title by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QML Window type instead of Dialog and specify its [flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#flags-prop) property as [Qt.Dialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum).